# Could not find action, lane or variable 'update_plist'

Tags: android, ios, react-native, native, fastlane

when running fastlane, fastlane error

```
[!] Could not find action, lane or variable 'update_plist'. Check out the documentation for more details: https://docs.fastlane.tools/actions
```

Did anyone ever experience this problem?
fastlane 2.28.3

Comment: Could you post part of the code where you call this 'update_plist'? You have the fastlane pretty outdated tho

Answer (score 1):

Your Fastlane version is almost 3 years old! `2.28.3` was released on Apr 21, 2017. This indicates the problem, **you have to upgrade the Fastlane version**.

Checked, and the `update_plist` command works fine on the latest Fastlane version which is currently `2.143.0`.

**Upgrade:**

- If you used [Homebrew](https://brew.sh) to install Fastlane, reinstall it:

  ```
  brew cask uninstall fastlane
  brew uninstall fastlane

  brew install fastlane
  ```
- If you used RubyGems to install Fastlane, you can remove it by:

  ```
  sudo gem uninstall fastlane
  sudo gem install fastlane -NV
  ```